# How to create a variable based on another using if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I need in 2nd column a count of how many times observation is in 1st column. Here, 2nd column should have values 1,2,3,1,2,1,2. This code doesn't work.

`x <- c(11,11,11,22,22,33,33)   y <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1) df <- data.frame(x,y)`

```
i <- 1    for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
if(df[i+1,1] == df[i,1]){df[i+1,2] <- 2}
 if(df[i+2,1] == df[i,1]){df[i+2,2 <- 3}
  else df[i+2,2] <- 1}
```

Comment: what about tagging the question whit the language

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(z=cumsum(y)) %>% ungroup()
# A tibble: 7 × 3
# x     y     z
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1    11     1     1
# 2    11     1     2
# 3    11     1     3
# 4    22     1     1
# 5    22     1     2
# 6    33     1     1
# 7    33     1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try base R:

```
unlist(by(x, x, seq_along), use.names = F)
# or 
ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sequence` and `rle` like

```
 sequence(rle(x)$length)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1 2
```

So

```
df$y <- sequence(rle(x)$length)
```

`rle` produces an object with the lengths of runs of repeated values as well as the values themselves. By feeding these lengths to `sequence`, we can produce counts from 1 to each of these values.

Comment: Not a problem @a-gore. You can choose which ever solution you like best by clicking on the check mark next to the question. This and upvoting questions/answers that you like  (when you get enough reputation) provide some incentives for those SO participants. Adding thank you comments is generally discouraged.